# MPI_Allreduce() in a recursive Tree walk

Tags: recursion, mpi

I have a tree structure on every processor (Quadtree) and walk through theses trees using the following function:

```
void treeWalk(TreeNode *t){
    if(t != NULL){
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            treeWalk(t->child[i]);
        }

        // Start operation on *t
        if (isSpecificNode(t) == TRUE){
            // Do stuff
        }
        // End operation on *t

    }
}
```

The tree structure on every processor is not the same. If I reach a certain node (which every processor has, e. g. node number x) in a tree I want to use `MPI_Allreduce()` to sum up the node's values and send the result (the sum of all nodes) to all the other processors such that they can save the result of this action like `t->nodeValue = sumOfAllNodes;`. If I do the following it does not work:

```
    void treeWalk(TreeNode *t){
        if(t != NULL){
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                treeWalk(t->child[i]);
            }

            // Start operation on *t
            if (isSpecificNode(t) == TRUE){
                double thisNodeValue = t->nodeValue;
                double sumOfAllNodes = 0;
                MPI_Allreduce(&thisNodeValue, &sumOfAllNodes, 1,
                              MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                t->nodeValue = sumOfAllNodes;
            }
            // End operation on *t

        }
}
```

In this case after calling `MPI_Allreduce` the value of `t->nodeValue` is not the desired result. How do I use `MPI_Allreduce()` in a recursive function? Can I use other functions like `MPI_Barrier()` or `MPI_Wait()` to get the job done?

EDIT: To make my question more clear:

Let us assume that I have two trees with only two nodes. The left tree is on processor 1 and the right one on processor 2. Both processors do a recursive tree walk. If the processors reach the left node (which normally does not happen simultaneously) they call `MPI_Allreduce()` and compute `1+0 = 1`. After this operation both nodes on the left on every processor should be equal to 1 or `0+2=2` for the case of the right nodes.

### [image]

Comment: It's simple - you must call `MPI_Allreduce` in the same order with the same parameters for size / type / op on all processes within the communicator. Whether that is the case or not is impossible to tell from your given information. *"not the desired result"* is also extremely vague.

Comment: @Zulan What do you mean exactly by saying "in the same order with the same parameters [...] within the communicator"? What do I have to change to achieve that? I mean that the result of my `MPI_Allreduce()` call does not sum up the values of my nodes.

Comment: @Zulan I updated my question

Comment: Another way to put it is that you must call `MPI_Allreduce` on all processes on only corresponding nodes in the same sequence. We won't be able to tell you where things go wrong without a [mcve]. I would also advise to learn how to use a parallel debugger.

Comment: What Zulan means is that you have to guarantee that the order in which the desired nodes (those where the reduction is performed) are reached must be the same in all ranks. This is both a requirement of the MPI standard (the sequence of collective calls within a given communicator must be the same for all ranks in it) and a logical part of the algorithm since collective calls cannot be tagged. It might help if you, e.g., print the node IDs in each rank just before the reduction call and then compare it with the expectation.

Comment: @HristoIliev The reduction seems to work now. But I am testing it only with very small trees. All processors walk through their trees in the same manner. So the desired nodes are reached in the same order. But since the trees are not equal in size, some processor might be faster at node X than others. Could this be a problem? (Same order but not at the same time). Does `MPI_Allreduce()` wait until all processors reached node X? I can not find any information about that. Can you please be more specific about your last sentence? I would like to grasp your idea. Thank you!

Comment: There is no requirement that `MPI_Allreduce()` should be called at the same time. Ranks that arrive earlier will simply block in the call and wait until all other ranks do the same. This will result in work imbalance and bad parallel performance (wasted execution time), but will not prevent the program from running correctly. My last sentence was simply a suggestion to print the location on the tree for each rank whenever the reduction is to be preformed and manually check if the sequence of reduction calls is as expected.

Comment: @HristoIliev Now it is more clear to me. What would be in this case a better way to reduce the imbalance and the bad parallel performance?

Comment: As long as the reduced values are not needed immediately, you may replace `MPI_Allreduce` with `MPI_Iallreduce`. Keep a list of outstanding requests (returned by `MPI_Iallreduce`) and test them periodically to let the MPI library progress the calls. In any case, the slowest traverse will determine the runtime of the entire algorithm. The only true optimisation would be to ensure that the individual trees are or approximately the same shape and size, i.e. implement a form of work balancing.

Comment: @HristoIliev The reduced values are not needed immediately. Can I just repalce `MPI_Allreduce()` by `MPI_Iallreduce()` or do I have to do more changes if I want to work with `MPI_Iallreduce()`?

Comment: No, you cannot simply replace the calls. `MPI_Iallreduce` is a non-blocking call that returns back an MPI request. The requests have to be tested or waited on in order to ensure the completion of the operations. Besides, most MPI libraries are really single-threaded and only process non-blocking requests while they hold the execution control. That's why I said "keep a list of outstanding requests and test them periodically". Some MPI implementations have background progression threads, but I wouldn't rely on that.